# Website is denying access when requesting content

Tags: python

I am trying to collect the news history for a stock from a website using python.

The news load as you scroll down, so a number of requests are necessary for each stock.

After a few requests the website denies access, even after specifying the User-Agent and even after making it vary with each request. I also tried pausing the execution for a few seconds between requests. Nothing works.

Does anybody know how to go around this?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but this does not answer the question. While the program runs, I can navigate the website normally, so the website can tell my browser and my program apart. I thought that specifying a User-Agent resolved this, but apparently it doesn't. There has to be a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case somebody else runs into this issue, the package "fake-useragent" seems to provide a solution.

I simply randomized the user agent before each request.

The website continues to deny access, albeit just seldom, and one can bypass this with a simple loop.

(The same answer was deleted a few days ago because I included a link to the package. I think my answer is more helpful to whomever runs into this issue in the future than previous answers to similar questions and all of your stupid comments.)